# CssMinify breaks minification if using "slash" in css syntax (Asp.Net MVC)

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, minify

I'm using basic System.Web.Optimization.CssMinify for .NET.
All the settings are out of scope for my question, but you can see [MVC Bundling and Minification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification) for more details.

It is a production environment, already set up and it works great.
However, when using CSS syntax like
`grid-row: 1 / span 2`,
I receive the minification error:

> Expected number in right hand side of /, found span on line

[image]

Is there any escape character or BundleConfig option that I can use?
Thank you.

Comment: Are you using an older version?  I'd imagine you'd need the latest version for this to work as css grids are fairly new.  If you are...then this is probably a bug in their minification code which you should report to Microsoft!